# Debian 8: Installed Python 2.7.13 But No Pip; Packages Install to Wrong Path

Tags: python

I am running Debain 8 Jessie and have installed `python 2.7.13` into `/usr/local/bin`.

I do not have a new pip installed, I am still using the pip located at `/usr/bin/`. Any time I install a package using `pip`, they are installed to the `dist-packages` location of my new python install:

`/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`

**Question**

How do I get my pip installs to permanently install in `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`? What is even weirder, is that although these packages are installing to a location seemingly setup by my new install, I cannot import whatever I download when I am using `python2.7.13` via `/usr/local/bin/python`.

**PATH**

`/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin:`

**Better Yet**

How do I just get my `python2.7.13` install to see the installed packages from pip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this:

```
import sys
for p in sys.path: 
    print p     # or print(p) if you prefer.
```

Look for /usr/lib/python2.7

if not you'll want to

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7:/usr/lib/python2.7
```

in .bashrc or in a special (host-wide) script in /etc/profile.d/

If /usr/lib/python2.7/

Depending on the difference between your "stock" version and 2.7.13, you might not want to put stuff in /usr/lib/python2.7. On my system I'd really want to avoid *any* cross contamination, but that's something I'm a bit picky about.